# Where is the result of QGis Zonal Statistics?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.8

I just ran the Zonal Statistics in QGis, the progress bar went up to 100%, disappeared, and nothing happened. Where is the result? Or does this mean it crashed and there was an error? I haven't seen any new messages in the log (View > Panels > Log Messages).

**EDIT:** I found it! It has been added to the polygon layer. But this is horrible!!! I don't want it to modify my polygon layer!!! I want the data separate! How can it even think of modifying my layer without asking?

### Is there any way to let the Zonal Statistics put the data separately?

Comment: Are you sure it modified the **original** polygon layer? I think it's supposed to create a new layer with the results stored in it. Which QGIS version are you using?

Comment: @Joseph 2.8 Wien. Yes, it does modify the original...

Comment: Maybe update to a more recent version like 2.18 ltr or 3.2 :)

Comment: @Joseph are you sure it will help?

Answer (score 4):

Make a copy of the original shapefile before running the zonal stats tool. Be sure to actually create a new shapefile, not just a duplicate layer.

Run the zonal stats tool on the copy, not on the original. The result: stats are added to the copy as attributes. You now have several options to get the stats into a spreadsheet.

- Option one: Save the shapefile as a CSV. Open the CSV in Excel. It has all the original and new attributes, as well as a geometry column. Delete any unwanted columns.
- Option two: Copy the .dbf portion of the shapefile. change the extension to .xls. Open this file in Excel. It has all the original attributes, the new stats from the zonal stats tool, but no geometry column.
- Option three: Open the attribute table in QGIS. Select the entire table, copy and paste into a spreadsheet. Don't use this method if you have multipart geometries, because you will lose some data.

---

If you *already* ran the zonal stats tool on your original shapefile, first follow one of the above methods to get the zonal stats as a spreadsheet. Then open the attribute table in QGIS and delete the unwanted columns.

---

Tip: Always back up your data before running a tool that modifies the source data. If you can't tell by reading the tool documentation whether it modifies the source data, make a backup just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 1):

I just had exactly the same problem. I think the fields are supposed to be added to the polygon layer, but I guess there's a bug in it.

Try the zonal statistics plugin and run it from raster > zonal statistics > zonal statistics

Comment: that's exactly what I did.